# How to calcaule sum of columns in image using Matlab

Tags: matlab

Hi I need to find the sum of the first and last 5 columns in a binary image using Matlab. I have begun trying to calculate the sum of the first 5 using:

```
 total=sum(BW3(1:5));
```

However when i do:

```
 display(total);
```

this just returns 0 which is not correct. So I have also tried using

```
 total=cumsum(BW3(1:5));
```

and displaying the total but this also returned 0. I also read on documentation to try adding Dim and setting it to 1. However this did not work either.

I have included a link to the matrix of the first 12 rows of the image here:

http://www.filedropper.com/imagematrix

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Your image link is broken. When possible, just post code snippets instead of screenshots anyway. If your data is too big to post a code snippet, come up with a smaller data set that reproduced the problem. Anyway, you probably want `sum(BW3(:,[1 5]))`. The `[1 5]` selects columns 1 and 5; your `1:5` selects elements 1 through 5, and should be done along the 2nd dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the second index in a vector to index into columns. To account for all the elements in a column, i.e. to get all the row elements in a particular column, use colon `:` as the first index.

Thus, to get the sum of the first five columns which would produce an array of 5 numbers, you may do this -

```
total=sum(BW3(:,[1:5]))
```

We can extend this to get the sum of the first and last five columns which would be an array of 10 numbers -

```
total=sum(BW3(:,[1:5 end-4:end]))
```

After that, you may use `display(total);` to display the values.

Comment: `[1:5]` is equivalent to just `1:5`.

Comment: @Memming, The point was to explain how that can be extended for the case of first and last five columns, for which `[` and `]` are needed. So, those in the first case are there to showcase the extensiblity.

Comment: I need to place a seed in the first fifth row and column of the image or last 5th row and col of the image to perform seeded region growing. Can anyone guide me with the syntax for placing the seed?

Comment: @user1853871 I think that could form a new question. Post with some sample image(s) too.